# Invoke packaged bash script from Node.js CLI using commander.js

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, node-commander

I am trying to write a CLI with [commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/). I want to have a certain command in the CLI invoke a previously written bash script, as well as pass arguments to it. I know I can use `shell.exec()` for this like so inside "`index.js`":

```js
shellCommand = `./RunScripts/bashScript.sh ${options.option1} ${options.option2}`;
if (shell.exec(shellCommand).code !== 0) {
    // ...do things
}
```

This means I need to include the bash script with my package when I publish the CLI. Using `npm pack --dry-run`, I can see that the scripts do get included with the package. Here's a rough outline of the file system I have here:

```sh
├── my-cli-directory
│   ├── README.md
│   └── RunScripts
│      └── bashScript.sh
│   ├── package.json
│   └── index.js
```

When I publish my CLI and try to download it with `npm install ...` it gives me an error message that looks like this:

```sh
/bin/sh: ./RunScripts/bashScript.sh: No such file or directory
```

This would make sense, as I am trying to tell `shell.exec` to run something that should be available at that location. Instead, **how do I tell `shell.exec` to run the script packaged with my CLI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing how I reference the location of the bash script.

Instead of:

```sh
shellCommand = `./RunScripts/bashScript.sh ${options.option1} ${options.option2}`;
```

I ran:

```sh
shellCommand = `${__dirname}/RunScripts/bashScript.sh ${options.option1} ${options.option2}`;
```

I'd totally forgotten about the `__dirname` variable.